# C# Window is immediately closing after creating it

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Form1 browser = new Form1(textBoxUserName.Text.Trim(), textBoxOldPassword.Text.Trim(), textBoxNewPassword.Text.Trim());
browser.Shown += (o, t) => { this.Close(); }; 
browser.Show();
```

I want the new Window to show up and the old window to close.

What's happening is that the application is being shutdown automatically when the this.Close() is being called

I am using WinForms

Comment: I think child window closes when parent window is closed. You can try `Hide()` instead.

Comment: how do I prevent the startup form from Exiting the application?

Comment: if "this" is your main form, this.Close() will close your application. This is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your code is from your main form `ParentForm` and the message pump was started by

```
Application.Run(new ParentForm());
```

which ends when `ParentForm` is closed. To achieve what you're trying to do you can rather write:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Form form = new ParentForm();
    form.Show();

    Application.Run(); // starts the message pump
}
```

In this case you must explicitly call `Application.Exit()` to end your program, e.g.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosed();

        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

A more clean approach would make use of [`ApplicationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If your this is the first form from where your application is getting loaded and if you close it, the application will close.

Instead of this.Close()

Do write it as this.Hide().

Comment: What is heck is this....??

First thing this is a very basic concept in windows app and there is case that your comment is being stolen.

Its a fresh answer compiled by me.

There is only 3 minutes difference between your and my post so i might have not got a chance to read your comments.