# windows form close immediately after loading

Tags: c#, winforms

For some reason my windows form closes immediately after I run the program.  I can see the form for about a second and then it closes.  Here is my form load method

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustGen = new CustomerGenerator(); 
        fuelType = null; 

        //set data on form initialization.
        unleadedtank = 10000f;
        dieseltank = 10000f;
        u_price = 136.9f;
        d_price = 152.2f;

        //event subscriptions

        CustGen.CustomerReady += CustomerReadySub; //Subscribes to ready event
        CustGen.PumpProgress += PumpProgressSub; //subscribes to progress event
        CustGen.PumpingFinished += PumpingFinishedSub; //subscribes to stop event

    }
```

and here is my program.cs for that particular form, although this is automatically generated I wasn't sure if it was needed.

```
        [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

This is within the customerGenerator class

```
  public class CustomerGenerator
{
    public CustomerGenerator();

    public event CustomerGenerator.CustomerReadyHandler CustomerReady;
    public event CustomerGenerator.PumpingFinishedHandler PumpingFinished;
    public event CustomerGenerator.PumpProgressHandler PumpProgress;

    public void ActivatePump();
    public void Start();

    public delegate void CustomerReadyHandler(object sender, CustomerReadyEventArgs e);

    public delegate void PumpingFinishedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

    public delegate void PumpProgressHandler(object sender, PumpProgressEventArgs e);
}
```

I have ran the program and came across this after carrying out what one of the users said below in the comments.

```
 public void CustomerReadySub(object sender, CustomerReadyEventArgs fuel)
    {
        string CustReady = null;

        //checks what fuel is chosen and then activates the pump
        fuelType = fuel.SelectedFuel.ToString();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fuelType))
        {
            fTypeLabel.Text = fuelType;
```

It is this line that is throwing the exception.  Also it says "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

```
fuelType = fuel.SelectedFuel.ToString();
```

Thanks

Comment: How about showing all relevant code for starters..?

Comment: And if you remove the body of Form1_Load, it works?

Comment: have you stepped thru the code..? how is this defined `CustGen = new CustomerGenerator();`

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520096/c-sharp-window-is-immediately-closing-after-creating-it?rq=1

Comment: You have some code on CustomerGenerator constructor?

Comment: I will add the code from the CustomerGenerator constructor, the CustomerGenerator class is in a form of a DLL

Comment: Why don't you start the project using F5 (=Start Debugging) in visual studio and look at the exception that it's producing? If the debugger doesn't break on exceptions go into the menu Debug>Exceptions and make sure "Thrown" is checked for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Comment: I get this exception "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"

Comment: Which line of code generates that exception?

Comment: I will update the original post to show where the exception is

Comment: The posted code won't even compile. If you want help, start by providing exact information.

Comment: After some updates: Yopu are starting a thread somwewhere, no details posted. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/142003/60761)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also it says "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Use the following pattern to access controls on your form:

```
private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(new EventHandler(MyHandler), sender, e);
  else {
    // code to handle the event
  }
}
```

When you listen to events generated from some objects that are executed on a thread, the code that handles the event will be run on that thread. Whenever you access UI objects from threads other than those that created those objects you will get an exception. InvokeRequired checks if you're running on the UI thread and if not the method is invoked to run on the UI thread. This allows you to safely access the controls.

Comment: Hi Andreas,
Thanks for the input, I was just wondering if I have done this right...If you look above at my original post I have a CustomerReadySub would I just change MyHandler to CustomerReadySub?

Comment: Since you use custom event arguments `new EventHandler(MyHandler)` won't work and you have to use the appropriate delegate constructor e.g. `new EventHandler<CustomerReadyEventArgs>(CustomerReadySub), sender, customerReadyEventArgs);`. You can also cast the handler to an `Action<object, CustomerReadyEventArgs>`.